# How to pass data from POJO and Controller to Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, spring-boot

I am passing data from by controller as Json by using the `@ResponseBody` annotation. My problem is that ajax is not able to recognize the data from my controller. When i check the `typeof` data in ajax it tells me it is `undefined`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/basic/Json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody JsonResponse addCertJson(@Valid @ModelAttribute CertificateProgramme certificate, BindingResult result, Principal principal, Locale locale, MessageSource messageSource) {
        JsonResponse res = new JsonResponse();
        User user = (User) ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principal).getPrincipal();
        certificate.setUser(user);
        if(!result.hasErrors()){
            res.setStatus("SUCCESS");
        }else{
            res.setStatus("FAIL");
            List<FieldError> allErrors = result.getFieldErrors();
            List<ErrorMessage> errorMesages = new ArrayList<ErrorMessage>();
            for (FieldError objectError : allErrors) {
                errorMesages.add(new ErrorMessage(objectError.getField(), objectError.getField() + "  " + objectError.getDefaultMessage()));
            }
            res.setErrorMessageList(errorMesages);

        }
        certificateService.save(certificate);
        return res;
    }
```

Form

```
<form method="post" th:object="${certificate}"
      th:action="@{${action1}}" modelAttribute="employee" class="form-inline inline new-item editCert">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
    <div th:replace="common/layout :: flash"></div>
    <div class="error" ></div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend th:text="${heading}"> Personal Information</legend>
        <div class="row" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('fullName')}? 'error' : ''">
            <input type="text" id="fullName" class="form-control input-sm" th:field="*{fullName}"
                   placeholder="Full Name example Jane Doe"/>
            <div class="error-message" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('fullName')}" th:errors="*{fullName}"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('gender')}? 'error' : ''">
            <select th:field="*{gender}" class="form-control input-lg ">
                <option value="">[Select Gender]</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
            <div class="error-message" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('gender')}" th:errors="*{gender}"></div>
        </div>
```

Jquery file

```
 var $form = $('.editCert');
    var formData = $form.serialize();
    $form.on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(url,{
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
        }).done(function(response){
           if(response.status === 'SUCCESS'){
                 console.log('I am Okay' + response);
                  }else{
                  console.log('Error');
                   }
        }).fail(function(res){
            errorInfo = "";
                 for(i =0 ; i < res.errorMessageList.length ; i++){
                     errorInfo += "<br>" + (i + 1) +". " + response.errorMessageList[i].code;
                 }
                 $('.error').html("Please correct following errors: " + errorInfo);
            });
    });
```

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: We can't help you until you show us outer scope where `data`  is coming from

Comment: @luboskrnac I added the outer scope

Comment: What is response body? .see that with firebug or chrome network

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is you are returning a JsonResponse object, not a json string. Try parsing it to json.

1 more note, you are using the fail callback in the wrong way. It should be

```
fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
   console.log(errorThrown);
})
```

Comment: When i parse the JsonResponse object i get this error `VM2486:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: I mean you have to return json string from addCertJson() like  return parseJson(res)

Comment: As at jQuery 3.1, `http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/` parseJson has been deprecated. So i use did this `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(res);
              console.log(typeof(jsonObj));`

Comment: No. You have to parse it from server side. Let's say you use [Gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.2.4) to parse then your code in `addCertJson` method will look like
`certificateService.save(certificate); Gson gson = new Gson(); return gson.toJson(res);`

Comment: Okay i get you now